# Third time's the charm - Nondeterministic Stack / GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I've been trying to install the package `text` using Stack inside an Ubuntu VM. The funny thing is - it doesn't the work the first time (Stack stops with a segfault), it doesn't work the second time (an internal GHC error) but it works the third time.

The VM is set up using the following `Vagrantfile`.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
    vb.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.hostname = "stack-project"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "root-bootstrap.sh"
```

The `root-bootstrap.sh` file is

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

apt-get -qq update &>/dev/null
apt-get -qq install software-properties-common \
  pkg-config wget dpkg nano vim \
  &>/dev/null

# Haskell Stack
wget -qO- https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh

chown -R vagrant $HOME
```

After running `vagrant up && vagrant ssh` (the two files need to be put in the same folder), I checked that Stack was installed.

```
vagrant@stack-project:~$ stack --version
Version 1.6.3, Git revision b27e629b8c4ce369e3b8273f04db193b060000db (5454 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
```

I tried installing `text` next

```
vagrant@stack-project:~$ stack install --resolver lts-10.3 text
Writing implicit global project config file to: /home/vagrant/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
Using resolver: lts-10.3 specified on command line
Downloaded lts-10.3 build plan.
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.

Warning: Retry number 0 after a total delay of 0 us
         If you see this warning and stack fails to download, but running the
         command again solves the problem, please report here:
         https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3510
Downloaded ghc-8.2.2.
Installed GHC.
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading root
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading timestamp
Downloading snapshot
Downloading mirrors
Cannot update index (no local copy)
Downloading index
Updated package index downloaded
Update complete
Populated index cache.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I noticed that the VM has ~75 MB memory free when the segfault happens. On running it the second time,

```
vagrant@stack-project:~$ stack install --resolver lts-10.3 text
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.o )
Linking /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 ...
text-1.2.2.2: download
text-1.2.2.2: configure
text-1.2.2.2: build

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package text-1.2.2.2 using:
      /home/vagrant/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure (-6)
    Logs have been written to: /home/vagrant/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/text-1.2.2.2.log

    Configuring text-1.2.2.2...
    Preprocessing library for text-1.2.2.2..
    Building library for text-1.2.2.2..
    [ 1 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Encoding.Error ( Data/Text/Encoding/Error.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Encoding/Error.o )
    [ 2 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Builder.Int.Digits ( Data/Text/Internal/Builder/Int/Digits.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Builder/Int/Digits.o )
    [ 3 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Builder.RealFloat.Functions ( Data/Text/Internal/Builder/RealFloat/Functions.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Builder/RealFloat/Functions.o )
    [ 4 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Utf16 ( Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Utf16.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Utf16.o )
    [ 5 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Utf32 ( Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Utf32.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Utf32.o )
    [ 6 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Functions ( Data/Text/Internal/Functions.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Functions.o )
    [ 7 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Read ( Data/Text/Internal/Read.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Read.o )
    [ 8 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Unsafe ( Data/Text/Internal/Unsafe.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Unsafe.o )
    [ 9 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Unsafe.Shift ( Data/Text/Internal/Unsafe/Shift.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Unsafe/Shift.o )
    [10 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Array  ( Data/Text/Array.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Array.o )
    [11 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Unsafe.Char ( Data/Text/Internal/Unsafe/Char.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Unsafe/Char.o )
    [12 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Utf8 ( Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Utf8.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Utf8.o )
    [13 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal ( Data/Text/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal.o )
    [14 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Search ( Data/Text/Internal/Search.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Search.o )
    [15 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Fusion.Size ( Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/Size.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/Size.o )
    [16 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Fusion.Types ( Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/Types.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/Types.o )
    [17 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Fusion.CaseMapping ( Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/CaseMapping.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/CaseMapping.o )
    [18 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Fusion.Common ( Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/Common.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Fusion/Common.o )
    [19 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Unsafe ( Data/Text/Unsafe.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Unsafe.o )
    [20 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Private ( Data/Text/Internal/Private.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Private.o )
    [21 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Fusion ( Data/Text/Internal/Fusion.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Fusion.o )
    [22 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Show   ( Data/Text/Show.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Show.o )
    [23 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.Common ( Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Fusion/Common.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Fusion/Common.o )
    [24 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Encoding.Fusion ( Data/Text/Internal/Lazy/Encoding/Fusion.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Lazy/Encoding/Fusion.o )
    [25 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion ( Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Fusion.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Internal/Encoding/Fusion.o )
    [26 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Encoding ( Data/Text/Encoding.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Encoding.o )
    [27 of 44] Compiling Data.Text.Foreign ( Data/Text/Foreign.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text/Foreign.o )
    [28 of 44] Compiling Data.Text        ( Data/Text.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Text.o )
    ghc: internal error: Unable to commit 1048576 bytes of memory
        (GHC version 8.2.2 for x86_64_unknown_linux)
        Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

You'd think that re-running `stack install` would give the same GHC error again, right? Wrong.

```
vagrant@stack-project:~$ stack install --cabal-verbose --resolver lts-10.3 text
text-1.2.2.2: configure
text-1.2.2.2: build
text-1.2.2.2: copy/register
```

As a check, I tried using `stack ghci --ghc-options "-package text"` which worked fine and I could use the functions normally. I installed `megaparsec` (any library depending on `text` will do) and it installed fine.

What combination of a stack bug, a GHC bug and a ghost am I encountering here?

Other stuff that might be relevant:

1. [Ticket 4012](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4012) -  Compilation results are not deterministic. If I were guessing, this is the difference between the second time and the third time. The milestone version is currently 8.4.1, whereas the GHC in lts-10.3 is 8.2.2.
2. An [ICFP 2016 paper](https://conf.researchr.org/event/icfp-2016/hiw-2016-papers-ghc-determinism) (indirectly?) claiming that GHC 8.0.2 is deterministic.

Comment: GHC 8.0.2 tries to be *more* deterministic. I think maybe the interface files are deterministic, or something like that.

Comment: It may be that GHC runs out of memory trying to build a bunch of things at once, but when it has some build products on hand it can finish the job. Just guessing.

Comment: @dfeuer, you're right - I tried playing around with the memory allocated to the VM and it does work fine with 1.5GB instead of 1GB.

Comment: @dfeuer can you post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted?